# Dynamic JSON scraped from a website detect truncated data

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON data which dynamically change after games has been played. This JSON shows the recent played games. The problem is that these games is scraped and on the website some of the team names is shorted like:

```
 Copen...
```

where the real would be Copenhagen

Is there an good way of checking for this and change it or would a huge if statement?

And would this be a bad idea and just stick to the original?

Comment: who populate the JSON, where do you get it from? What does the JSON looks like? What have you tried so far? you need to provide a maximum information for the community to help. We are not next to you, please explain a bit more your question.

Comment: JSON values are not shortened. Check who generates JSON and why it shortens values.

Comment: The data is truncated which mean i cant scrape the full teamname, i was just wondering whether i manually could make a if statement for the names which is truncated? or there is a better way beside making a huge if statement